# ngx-toastr error doesn't work in else statement for login

Tags: angular, toast, toastr

I'm implementing ngx-toastr on my Angular login page.  For some reason, the success message works, but the error doesn't.  I tried using the error message in the successful login statement, and it worked, but it doesn't show in the failed login statement.  My code (login method at the bottom):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-modal',
  templateUrl: './login-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-modal.component.css']
})
export class LoginModalComponent implements OnInit {

  //Hold user data from form to send to Mongo
  user = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };


  constructor(
    private session: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    public vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {


  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }



  showError() {
    this.toastr.error('Username and/or password incorrect.');
  }


  showSuccess() {
    this.toastr.success('Success!');
  }

  login() {
    this.session.login(this.user)
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result === true) {
          //login successful
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          this.showSuccess();

        } else {
          //login failed
          this.showError();                     <--DOESN'T WORK
          console.log('result not ok', result)
        }
      });
  }



}
```

Seems like it should be an obvious thing, but I've tried putting it in my service, as well, and it still doesn't work.  I've tried changing my `else` around to put the error first, etc., but nothing.  Curious whether anyone has run into this, or if there's something obvious that I'm missing here?

EDIT:  If curious, using Angular v.5.

Comment: Are your login API call returns an error in case of incorrect login or it will return 200 OK with false?

Comment: Thanks for your message.  I return a 401 Unauthorized error @VitaliiChmovzh

Comment: That's why you never get to the else statement. I will post an answer in a moment.

Comment: Interesting - would not have guessed.  ok @VitaliiChmovzh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as your server returns 401 error, you will never get into `result => { ... }` block because it will be processed as an error. Tweak your `login()` function in the following way

```
login() {
    this.session.login(this.user)
      .subscribe(result => {
          //login successful
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          this.showSuccess();
      }, error => {
          //login failed
          this.showError();                     
          console.log('result not ok', result)
      });
}
```

and it will work!

Comment: This helped me better understand error handling as well.